# Numpy indexing in reverse order with roll

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a 2d big matrix and I want to extrapolate submatrices from elements considering the first neighbours, with **periodic boundaries**.
I did something like this:

```
neighborhood = big_matrix[x-1:x+2, y-1:y+2]
```

but this only works for every `[x, y]` in the middle of the matrix but not for elements in the borders like `[0, 0]` where **indexing like `[-1:2, -1:2]` gives an empty array**.
I think I have to use some sort of 2D `np.roll` but I don't know how to do it in a clean and efficient way.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By playing with the roll function in numpy I found the solution (roll the arrays of +1-x, +1-y and get the first 3x3 matrix)

```py
np.roll(big_matrix, (1-x, 1-y), axis=(0, 1))[:3, :3]
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it is the solution you are looking for:

```
import numpy as np

x=0
y=0

big_matrix = np.random.randint(5, size=(10,10))
print(big_matrix)
#new_matrix = big_matrix[x-1 :x+2, y-1:y+2]
new_matrix = big_matrix[x if x==0 else x-1 :x+2, y if y==0 else y-1:y+2]
new_matrix
```

Comment: Not really, I was looking forward for something with periodicity, but I think I figured out

Comment: If you figured the answer out, would you paste it?

Comment: I don't think this is what OP was looking for.  He wanted the last column to precede the first column, and the first column to be after the last column.  Likewise for rows.

Comment: I commented my solution! Just rolling with vectors works, but I find it pretty ugly and not-pythonic imho